# expectation of function of exponential

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I need to compute the following integral

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x\,\left\{\vphantom{\LARGE A}%
1- \left[\vphantom{\Large A}1- \exp(-a\,x^{\alpha}) \right]^M
\right\}\,{\rm d}x
\qquad
\mbox{with}\quad \alpha > 0\quad\mbox{and}\quad a,M > 0. 
$$

Is this a known integral ( if possible, without approximating the exponential function ) ?.

Comment: Bob, The formula isn't rendered very clearly to me (subscript and superscripts). So I rewrote it slightly. Hope its ok with you. Also, check that I haven't made a mistake :)

Comment: Is the thing inside the square brackets, the CDF instead of the PDF of the distribution? Are you calculating the $E[X]$ for some distribution (related to exponentials)?

Comment: yes it's an expectation. I just fixed a typo, now it should converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that $M$ is an integer. Let $\beta=1/\alpha$. Then substituting $x\to x^\beta$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x\left[1-(1-\exp(-ax^\alpha))^M\right]\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty \beta x^{2\beta-1}\left[1-(1-\exp(-ax))^M\right]\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty \beta x^{2\beta-1}\left[\sum_{k=1}^M(-1)^{k-1}\binom{M}{k}\exp(-akx)\right]\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\beta\;a^{-2\beta}\;\Gamma(2\beta)\;\sum_{k=1}^M(-1)^{k-1}k^{-2\beta}\binom{M}{k}
\end{align}
$$
This can be evaluated as long as you can evaluate $\Gamma(2/\alpha)$.

Comment: ..... Anyway, the binomial theorem works for noninteger $M>0$ so long as you take the sum out to $\infty$ (and extend the binomial coefficient with gamma functions).

Comment: @anon: You don't even need to use $\Gamma$ to extend the binomial coefficient: $\displaystyle\binom{M}{k}=\frac{M(M-1)(M-2)...(M-k+1)}{k!}$ works for non-integer $M$.

Comment: in my case $M$ is integer, so I guess the result works as is

Comment: @Bob: I had a feeling $M\in\mathbb{Z}^+$

Comment: would it be possible to approximate it in a simpler form?

Comment: @Bob: perhaps with some assumptions like $M\to\infty$ or something like that, some asymptotics could be computed.  Did you have something in mind?